# python selenium to check if this text field is disabled or not

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This is the html code for a textarea that has been disabled from UI.

```
<div class="ftnt-input">
   <input class="" disabled="" name="group_name" type="text" value="Orange, APPLE">
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to verify that the text field is disabled in python selenium code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use is_enabled() method of web driver.

**Python**

```
driver.find_element_by_name("group_name").is_enabled
```

**Java**

```
driver.findElement(By.name("")).isEnabled();
```

It will return true if its enabled otherwise false.