# How to prevent python selenium from clicking element that is present, but disabled?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to write a code that scrapes all reviews from a single hotel on tripadvisor. The code runs through all pages except the last one, where it has a problem. It says that the problem is the next.click() in the loop. I am assuming this is because "next" is still present in the element, but just disabled. Anyone know how to fix this problem? I basically want it to not try to click next when it reaches the last page/when it is disabled, but still technically present. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#maybe3.1

from argparse import Action
from calendar import month
from distutils.command.clean import clean
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from os import link
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil import relativedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import requests 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Extract the HTML and create a BeautifulSoup object.
url = ('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g46833-d256905-Reviews-Knights_Inn_South_Hackensack-South_Hackensack_New_Jersey.html#REVIEWS')

user_agent = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) \
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
            Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Find and extract the data elements.

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="component_15"]/div/div[3]/div[13]/div')))
#explicit wait here
next = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//a[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]')
here = next.is_displayed()
while here == True:

    time.sleep(2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    time.sleep(2)
    Titles = []
    for title in soup.findAll('a',{'Qwuub'}):
        Titles.append(title.text.strip())

    reviews = []
    for review in soup.findAll('q',{'class':'QewHA H4 _a'}):
        reviews.append(review.text.strip())
    
    next.click()
    if here != True:
        time.sleep(2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        time.sleep(8)
        break

# Create the dictionary.
dict = {'Review Title':Titles,'Reviews/Feedback':reviews}

# Create the dataframe.
datafr = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
datafr.head(10)

# Convert dataframe to CSV file.
datafr.to_csv('hotels1.855.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question might be in the same vein like:
[python selenium to check if this text field is disabled or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513821/python-selenium-to-check-if-this-text-field-is-disabled-or-not)

You can check if an element is enabled with:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id").is_enabled
```

You can also wrap the code in a try/except block.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it didn't seem to work. Where would you recommend placing this line?

Comment: Maybe try ## while here == True and next.is_enabled() 
Or go for try/except

Answer (score 0):

```
page=2
while True:
    try:
        #your code
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"//a[@class='pageNum ' and text()='{page}']").click()
        page+=1
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        break
```

Should be a simple loop to go through all pages wait till the a tag in question is not valid anymore.

```
import time
```

Comment: Thanks. I put it in, but the only problem is that it only scrapes the last page of reviews. Is there a workaround to make it scrape all pages?

I put #your code after the except, allowing me to scrape the last page, but when I put it in the Try part, it doesn't scrape it all. It does let me go through all the pages though.

Comment: You initialize reviews to empty each time.

Comment: So put it outside the loop.

Comment: Update:It works so much better now! The only problem is that it scrapes the first page twice. Is there any way to workaround this problem? Other than that, the code works wonderfully. Thanks for the help so far btw!

Comment: it should scrape then go to the next page which is why I assumed the first click to be page =2.

Comment: hey could you possibly help me with some other parts of my code? I could pay you to help. If interested let me know!

Comment: sure just paypal me and post the question.